# Creating a Clojure future without it running

Tags: clojure, future

I have a basic Clojure script containing:

```
(def test
    (future
        (loop []
            (println "Running")
            (recur))))
```

However, if I execure the file with:

```
java -cp clojure-1.3.0.jar clojure.main test.clj
```

Then the screen fills with "Running". How can I change it so the future runs when I want it?

Note: I realise this will run forever, it's just an example of my problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A future that doesn't run immediately is just a function with no arguments.

So:

```
(defn test []
  (println "Running")
  (recur))
```

...Later...

```
(future (test))
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you :D I also didn't realise you could leave out the (loop [] ...) if the function required no arguments.

Comment: @DeanBarnes `recur` goes back to the most "recent" recur anchor point. The two things defined by the language to be recur anchor points are `loop` and `fn`, so you only need a `loop` if you want to recur to a different point, or with different bindings, than your function head.